# while uploading a cloudfile in rackspace cloud using openstack.net i get net.openstack.Core.Exceptions.Response.BadServiceRequestException

Tags: openstack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

While uploading a file to rackspace cloud using the CreateObjectFromFile method from my local machine, it goes though fine. but when i do it from a client machine i get net.openstack.Core.Exceptions.Response.BadServiceRequestException.

```
ContainerID: 1644 
srcfileName: \\10.5.48.2\XMLGateway\BOOutBox\PJR340131023160359529217.xml 
desfileName: 1644_PJR340131023160359529217.xml

cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(inStrContainerID, inStrSrcFilePath, strDesFileName);
```

I checked for documentation on this exception and i cannot find anything useful.

EDIT:
here is the error stack

```
net.openstack.Core.Exceptions.Response.BadServiceRequestException: Invalid request body: unable to parse Auth data. Please review XML or JSON formatting.
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.Validators.HttpResponseCodeValidator.Validate(Response response)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.GeographicalCloudIdentityProvider.ExecuteRESTRequest[T](CloudIdentity identity, String urlPath, HttpMethod method, Object body, Dictionary`2 queryStringParameter, Boolean isRetry, Boolean isTokenRequest, String token, Int32 retryCount, Int32 retryDelay, Func`7 callback)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.GeographicalCloudIdentityProvider.ExecuteRESTRequest[T](CloudIdentity identity, String urlPath, HttpMethod method, Object body, Dictionary`2 queryStringParameter, Boolean isRetry, Boolean isTokenRequest, String token, Int32 retryCount, Int32 retryDelay)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.GeographicalCloudIdentityProvider.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetUserAccess>b__b()
at net.openstack.Core.Caching.UserAccessCache.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Get>b__4(String k)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func`2 addValueFactory, Func`3 updateValueFactory)
at net.openstack.Core.Caching.UserAccessCache.Get(String key, Func`1 refreshCallback, Boolean forceCacheRefresh)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.GeographicalCloudIdentityProvider.GetUserAccess(CloudIdentity identity, Boolean forceCacheRefresh)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.CloudIdentityProvider.GetUserAccess(CloudIdentity identity, Boolean forceCacheRefresh)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.ProviderBase`1.GetServiceEndpoint(CloudIdentity identity, String serviceName, String region)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.ProviderBase`1.GetPublicServiceEndpoint(CloudIdentity identity, String serviceName, String region)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.CloudFilesProvider.GetServiceEndpointCloudFiles(CloudIdentity identity, String region, Boolean useInternalUrl)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.CloudFilesProvider.CreateObject(String container, Stream stream, String objectName, Int32 chunkSize, Dictionary`2 headers, String region, Action`1 progressUpdated, Boolean useInternalUrl, CloudIdentity identity)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.CloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(String container, String filePath, String objectName, Int32 chunkSize, Dictionary`2 headers, String region, Action`1 progressUpdated, Boolean useInternalUrl, CloudIdentity identity)
at ?.?.?(String ?, String ?, String ?, String ?, String ?, String& ?, Boolean& ?, String& ?)
```

Edit 2:
Ok after updating the dll to the new versions, this is the stacktrace:

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.203.3.30:443
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at JSIStudios.SimpleRESTServices.Client.RestServiceBase.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Stream>b__5(HttpWebRequest req)
at JSIStudios.SimpleRESTServices.Client.RestServiceBase.<>c__DisplayClass9.<ExecuteRequest>b__8()
at JSIStudios.SimpleRESTServices.Client.RequestRetryLogic.Execute(Func`1 callback, IEnumerable`1 non200SuccessCodes, Int32 retryCount, Nullable`1 retryDelay)
at JSIStudios.SimpleRESTServices.Client.RestServiceBase.ExecuteRequest(Uri url, HttpMethod method, Func`3 responseBuilderCallback, Dictionary`2 headers, Dictionary`2 queryStringParameters, RequestSettings settings, Func`2 executeCallback)
at JSIStudios.SimpleRESTServices.Client.RestServiceBase.Stream(Uri url, HttpMethod method, Func`3 responseBuilderCallback, Stream content, Int32 bufferSize, Int64 maxReadLength, Dictionary`2 headers, Dictionary`2 queryStringParameters, RequestSettings settings, Action`1 progressUpdated)
at JSIStudios.SimpleRESTServices.Client.RestServiceBase.Stream(Uri url, HttpMethod method, Stream content, Int32 bufferSize, Int64 maxReadLength, Dictionary`2 headers, Dictionary`2 queryStringParameters, RequestSettings settings, Action`1 progressUpdated)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.ProviderBase`1.StreamRESTRequest(CloudIdentity identity, Uri absoluteUri, HttpMethod method, Stream stream, Int32 chunkSize, Int64 maxReadLength, Dictionary`2 queryStringParameter, Dictionary`2 headers, Boolean isRetry, RequestSettings requestSettings, Action`1 progressUpdated)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.CloudFilesProvider.CreateObject(String container, Stream stream, String objectName, String contentType, Int32 chunkSize, Dictionary`2 headers, String region, Action`1 progressUpdated, Boolean useInternalUrl, CloudIdentity identity)
at net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.CloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(String container, String filePath, String objectName, String contentType, Int32 chunkSize, Dictionary`2 headers, String region, Action`1 progressUpdated, Boolean useInternalUrl, CloudIdentity identity)
at ?.?.?(String ?, String ?, String ?, String ?, String ?, String& ?, Boolean& ?, String& ?
```

So does have to do with with firewall settings on the client machine?

Comment: To confirm, is this custom code against our API or using one of the SDKs?

Comment: am using the openstack.net sdk

Comment: OP - I'm following up with the guy who wrote the .NET SDK to see if there is a more verbose error message available to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A newer release of the SDK is available through NuGet. Two of the many changes included in that release are the following:

1. Removed `GeographicalCloudIdentityProvider` (a class only used inside the SDK itself, nevertheless this is the part of your stack trace that indicated you were using an old version of the SDK)
2. Added the ability for `ResponseException` (the base class of `BadServiceRequestException` and several others) to include detailed information about the cause of the problem as part of the exception.

(Applies to openstack.net 1.2.x only): Due to a limitation in the SDK dependencies that we are working to resolve ASAP, you'll need to explicitly install one of the SDK dependencies before installing the SDK. The instructions for this are included in the comment marked **UPDATE** on the following page: [openstacknetsdk/openstack.net#203](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/issues/203)

Comment: ok i've updated the SDK, the error i'm getting now is "Unable to connect to the remote server". Why is it that am able to connect and upload from my local machine, but not from the client machine? does have to do with some firewall settings on the client machine?

Comment: UPDATE: the ipaddress 173.203.3.30 from the stack trace, i'm able to ping that from my local machine. i disabled all firewall and pinged from the client machine and i get connection timed out, no response.

Comment: @gopstar - Join this chat room and we can work real time: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39944/rackspace